# Having issues with Intellij diagram generator

Tags: intellij-idea, class-diagram

I am using Intellij IDEA 2023.3.4 Ultimate edition with Oracle JDK 11.0.22.
When generated class diagram for two java classes, it is not showing inheritance relationship (arrows). Instead it is generating diagram shown here (when clicked on context menu-->Diagram-->Show Diagram)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3fRh.png)

Classes are defined as below:

public class MyFirstModule extends ModuleBase
public abstract class ModuleBase

These two classes are in different packages. (Not sure that matters).
I played with all options available in Diagram settings (enabled almost every setting). Also clicked on "Show Dependencies" button (top menu on diagram panel).

Does it require higher version of java or something?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Manoj G.

Comment: Related issue at JetBrains issues tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-346287